# Switching between browsers using Linktext in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, cross-browser

This is how you can switch  browsers pages using `linkText` in Selenium as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public class locatorsPractice {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/path");
    WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://browser url");

    String strMainWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Window title"+driver.getTitle());
    
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google")).click();
    Set <String> strHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String handle:strHandles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        String strTitle=driver.getTitle();
        if(strTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Google")) {
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
    }}
```